# Switching from Google+ Sign-In to the new Google Sign-In causes a BadParcelableException

Tags: android, google-play-services, proguard, google-signin, dexguard

I switched from the Google+ Sign-In to the new [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/) as part of Google Play Servies 8.3.0 and got a:

```
BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called CREATOR on class com.google.android.gms.auth.TokenDat
```

at:

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(getApplicationContext(), email, scopes);
```

How can I prevent the BadParcelableException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to prevent ProGuard/DexGuard from stripping needed classes within the new `com.google.android.gms.auth` package by adding:

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.auth.** { public *; }
```

to your `proguard-project.txt` or `dexguard-project.txt` file.